# IOS swift Web Socket SRWebSocket set response timeout

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, bots, socketrocket

I am using SRWebSocket/SocketRocket library in my app I am unable to set response timeout for it . I want to show a message if socket does not receive any data after few seconds

Following is my code

```
socketRocket = SRWebSocket(url: URL(string: streamUrl)!)
socketRocket?.delegate = self
socketRocket?.open()
```

Using following callback methods as well

```
func webSocketDidOpen(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!) {
    print("webSocketDidOpen")
    showTableView()
}

func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didCloseWithCode code: Int, reason: String!, wasClean: Bool) {
    getConversationId()
}

func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print("didFailWithError\(error)")
    showLErrorView()
}

func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didReceiveMessage message: Any!) {
}
```

here is link to library

https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket

Comment: Can you add the web socket library link that you are using?

Comment: aren't these delegate methods working?

Comment: updated question added library link

Comment: Hi @amodkanthe I think you should create an `Executer` object which can executes specific jobs after given time / sec with `Timer`. Then simply you can start timer and give a job to `Executer` in request case.

Comment: @amodkanthe I coudn't see any a way to set the timeout on the websocket connections in there. I know this does not answer your question, but have you looked into https://github.com/daltoniam/starscream library. I have used it and it has easy way to set it  `socket.disconnect(forceTimeout: 10, closeCode: CloseCode.normal.rawValue)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display some message when you don't get a response you can use a `Timer`, the basics it looks like that:

```swift
var timer: Timer?
var responseTimeout: TimeInterval = 15

func startTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: responseTimeout, repeats: false, block: {[weak self] timer in
        self?.onResponseTimeout()
    })
}

func onResponseTimeout() {
    print("Didn't get response")
}

func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didReceiveMessage message: Any!) {
    print(message)
    timer?.invalidate() //invalidate timer when you get a message
}
```

and then you can call `startTimer()` when it is needed i.e. when the socket is opened:

```swift
func webSocketDidOpen(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!) {
    print("webSocketDidOpen")
    showTableView()
    startTimer()
}
```

or after you send a message:

```swift
socketRocket?.send(message)
startTimer()
```

---

If you also want to set a timeout for connection (it is something separate from resopone timout), you can use `URLRequest` instead of `URL`:

```swift
let request = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: 30) //it is 30 sec connection timeout

socketRocket = SRWebSocket(urlRequest: request)
socketRocket?.delegate = self
socketRocket?.open()
```

---

Full class that supports both connection and response timeout:

```swift
import Foundation
import SocketRocket

class WebSocket: NSObject, SRWebSocketDelegate {

    var socketRocket: SRWebSocket?
    var timer: Timer?

    var responseTimeout: TimeInterval = 15

    func open(url: URL, connectionTimeout: TimeInterval = 10) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: connectionTimeout)
        socketRocket = SRWebSocket(urlRequest: request)
        socketRocket?.delegate = self
        socketRocket?.open()
    }

    func send(message: String) {
        socketRocket?.send(message)
        startTimer()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: responseTimeout, repeats: false, block: {[weak self] timer in
            self?.onResponseTimeout()
        })
    }

    func onResponseTimeout() {
        print("Didn't get response")
    }

    func webSocketDidOpen(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!) {
        print("webSocketDidOpen")
        startTimer()
    }

    func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didCloseWithCode code: Int, reason: String!, wasClean: Bool) {
        print("closed with code: \(code), reason: \(reason), wasClean: \(wasClean)")
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
        print("didFailWithError\(error)")
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func webSocket(_ webSocket: SRWebSocket!, didReceiveMessage message: Any!) {
        print(message)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```